# Link to a modal window from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Title says it all, I would like to trigger a jQuery event that opens a unique model window depending on which URL is used. I've looked at a few solutions and all of them seem to require bootstrap which I am not using or simply don't seem to work for me.

I think i understand the logic, I'm just not sure how to actually code it and would be grateful for some help. Here is my thinking:

**[STEP 1]**
On page load, check the URL.

- If the the url is normal e.g. "www.domain.com/example", don't do anything.
- If the url has a substring on the end e.g. "www.domain.com/example/#red", "www.domain.com/example/#green", or "www.domain.com/example/#blue" etc., set that substring to a variable. In this case the variable would equal either red, green, or blue.

**[STEP 2]**
Insert the variable where the line of code says [color] and execute.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
        $(".details, #[color]details").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I think you just want to know how to get the hash part of the url? You can get it with `window.location.hash`.

Comment: @Jhon I don't completely understand what you want. Do you want to popup the color from URL to a modal window ?

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution sorry for the confusion. Right now I have a single modal width the class .details. There are a bunch of buttons and when one is pressed it changes the content of the .detail modal. Each button has its own id, #[color]details. What i wanted to do was instead of having to click a specific button, i would link a user to the page, and the url would provide enough info for the specific button to be triggered without having to be clicked manually. However, if the URL doesnt contain a substring at the end I dont want the modal to open which is why I wanted to check the URL first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use with [`window.location.hash`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp). its will get the hash value form url with`#` .so no need to add `#` in the dom

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
  if(window.location.hash.trim().match(/(\w+)/)){
            $(".details,"+window.location.hash+"details").trigger('click');
}
    });
```

Comment: `window.location.hash` returns the hash part including the symbol `#` so you should remove it from the selector.

Comment: '#' is not there see the snippet .i was already removed @MohitBhardwaj

Comment: Thanks prasad, would the best way to check and see if the URL is normal be checking the string length of window.location.hash? So that if its length is equal to 0 then the function would not run? As it is my function will run regardless of the url.

Comment: @John.. yes `window.location.hash.length` > 0 is validate.Better use recognise the pattern see my updated answer .Because `#` only there the length alos `>0`. so only i was switched with pattern

Comment: Thanks @prasad, your updated solution is working perfectly. Much appreciated! One more thing if its not too much. How would I alter the solution to work if I didn't want the '#' character in my link. For example if the URL was "www.domain.com/example/red" instead of "www.domain.com/example/#red". Is this possible?

Comment: @John .Doesn't no way.if you alter the `url` the page will be reloaded.The hash value was removed.But you are clear the `hash` value to add with end of the function like this `window.location.hash=" "`.but `#` symbol  is there in end of the url =>`www.domain.com/example/#`

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.referrer to get the Page URL. 
Store it in a variable to fetch the last segment or the URL using substr().

Then check it in conditional operator if the last part is your desired text, add it to your class and trigger.
 I ll paste my code which I used on the next page to trigger tab change for some requirement. I hope this will work for you too, hopefully. Thank you.

> $(document).ready(function () {

```
  var referrer =  document.referrer;     // Get the Url of the previous page
  var lastPathSegment = referrer.substr(referrer.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);  // extracts the last part e.g. the page name

  if(lastPathSegment == "invoices.php"){
    customer_detail_content();
    $('a[href="#tab_6_2"]').trigger('click');
   }
```